# Multi-threading -- a faster way?

Tags: java, multithreading, time

I have a class with a getter `getInt()` and a setter `setInt()` on a certain field, say field

```
Integer Int;
```

of an object of a class, say `SomeClass`.

The `setInt()` here is synchronized-- `getInt()` isn't.

I am updating the value of `Int` from within multiple threads. 
Each thread is getting the value `Int`, and setting it appropriately. 
The threads aren't sharing any other resources in any way.

The code executed in each thread is as follows.

```
public void update(SomeClass c) {

        while (<condition-1>) // the conditions here and the calculation of 
                                   // k below dont have anything to do 
                                   // with the members of c
            if (<condition-2>) {
                // calculate k here 
                synchronized (c) {                        
                        c.setInt(c.getInt()+k); 
                    //    System.out.println("in "+this.toString());
                }
            }  
}
```

The `run()` method is just invoking the above method on the members updated from within the constructor by the params passed to it:

```
public void run() { update(c); }
```

When I run this on large sequences, the threads aren't interleaving much-- i see one thread executing for long without any other thread running in between.

There must be a better way of doing this.

I can't change the internals of `SomeClass`, or of the class invoking the threads.

How can this be done better?

TIA.

//=====================================

EDIT:

I'm not after manipulating the execution sequence of the threads. They all have the same priority. It`s just that what i see in the outcome is suggesting that the threads aren't sharing the execution time evenly-- one of them, once takes over, executing on. However, I can't see why this code should be doing this.

Comment: Can you please show the code of your public void run() method? Better if you paste your whole code related to thread like how you are making multiple threads and how starting them. I doubt if multithreading is actually being achieved in your code.

Comment: Are you having update() and run() method in same class?

Comment: yes, they are in the same class

Comment: You want to know how to overcome a possible starvation of other threads? If so i would suggest to add starvation somewhere into the question, since it is a known problem.

Comment: i dont think starvation is an issue here

Comment: Check updates to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It`s just that what i see in the outcome is suggesting that the threads aren't sharing the execution time evenly

Well, this is exactly what you don't want if you are after efficiency. Yanking a thread from being executed and scheduling another thread is generally very costly. Therefore it's actually advantageous to do `one of them, once takes over, executing on`. Of course, when this is overdone you could see higher throughput but longer response time. In theory. In practice, JVMs thread scheduling is well tuned for almost all purposes, and you don't want to try changing it in almost all situations. As a rule of thumb, if you are interested in response times in millisecond order, you probably want to stay away messing with it.

tl;dr: It's not being inefficient, you probably want to leave it as it is.

**EDIT:**
Having said that, using an `AtomicInteger` may help in performance, and is in my opinion less error prone than using a lock (`synchronized` keyword). You need to be hitting that variable really very hard in order to get a measurable benefit though.

Comment: this makes sense. are there any references that could pin this down? i was wondering whether the synchronized & asynchronized methods within the syn'd block would be an issue. and whether some other types of locks can do better.

Comment: I'd refer to the book `Java Concurrency in Practice`. It's the best resource on this topic and it discusses your questions. As for synch/lock, as of JDK6 there is no difference. If you are literary incrementing an integer, you have to be hitting it with ridiculous load in order for basic concurrency facilities becoming an issue. I'd really look elsewhere for performance improvements if I were you. The book also talks about this.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK provides a nice solution for multi threaded int access, AtomicInteger:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Answer (score 1):

As [Enno Shioji has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24279320/2711488), letting one thread proceed might be the most efficient way to execute your code in some scenarios.

It depends on how much cost the thread synchronization imposes in relation to the other work of your code (which we don’t know). If you have a loop like:

```
while (<condition-1>)
    if (<condition-2>) {
        // calculate k here 
        synchronized (c) {                        
            c.setInt(c.getInt()+k); 
        }
    }
```

and the test for condition-1 and condition-2 and the calculation of `k` is rather cheap compared to the synchronization cost, the Hotspot optimizer might decide to reduce the overhead by transforming the code to something like this:

```
synchronized (c) {                        
    while (<condition-1>)
        if (<condition-2>) {
            // calculate k here 
            c.setInt(c.getInt()+k); 
        }
}
```

(or a rather more complicated structure by performing loop unrolling and span the `synchronized` block over multiple iterations). The bottom line is that the optimized code might block other threads longer but let the one owning the lock finish faster resulting in an overall faster execution.

This does not mean that a single-threaded execution was the fastest way to handle your problem. It also doesn’t mean that using an `AtomicInteger` here would be the best option to solve the problem. It would create a higher CPU load and possibly a small acceleration but it doesn’t solve your real mistake:

It is completely unnecessary to update `c` within the loop at a high frequency. After all, your threads do not depend on seeing updates to `c` timely. It even looks like they are not using it at all. So the correct fix would be to move the update out of the loop:

```
int kTotal=0;
while (<condition-1>)
    if (<condition-2>) {
        // calculate k here
        kTotal += k;
    }
synchronized (c) {                        
    c.setInt(c.getInt()+kTotal); 
}
```

Now, all threads can run in parallel (assuming the code you haven’t posted here doesn’t contain inter-thread dependencies) and the `synchronization` cost is reduced to a minimum. You could still change it to an `AtomicInteger` as well but that’s not that important anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to this

> i see one thread executing for long without any other thread running in between.
>   There must be a better way of doing this.

You can not control how threads will be executed. JVM does this for you, and does not like you to interfere in its work.

**Still you can look at `yield` as your option, but that also does not ensure same thread will not be picked again.**

> The java.lang.Thread.yield() method causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow other threads to execute.

Comment: No, don't use `yield` unless you are working on code that counts response time in microseconds...

Answer (score 0):

I've found it better to use wait() and notify() than yield. Check out this example (seen from a book)-

```
class Q {
int n;
boolean valueSet = false;
synchronized int get() {
if(!valueSet)
wait(); //handle InterruptedException
//
valueSet = false;
notify();//if thread waiting in put, now notified
}

synchronized void put(int n) {
if(valueSet)
wait(); //handle InterruptedException
//
valueSet = true;
//if thread in get waiting then that is resumed now
notify();
}
}
```

or you could try using sleep() and join the threads in the end in main() but that isn't a foolproof way

Answer (score -1):

You are having `public void update(SomeClass c)` method in your code and this method is an `instance method` in which you are passing the object as parameter.

`synchronized(c)` in your code is doing nothing. Let me show you with some example,

So if you will make different objects of this class and then try to make them different threads like,

```
   class A extends Thread{
          public void update(SomeClass c){}
          public void run(){
               update(c)
          }
          public static void main(String args[]){

               A t1 = new A();
               A t2 = new A();

               t1.start();
               t2.start();

          }
   }
```

Then both of these t1 & t2 will have their own copies of update method and the reference variable `c` which you are making synchronized will also be different for both  the threads. t1 calls its own update() method and t2 calls its own update() method. So synchronization won't work.

Synchronization will work when you have something common for both the threads.

Something like,

```
   class A extends Thread{

          static SomeClass c;

          public void update(){
                synchronized(c){

                }
          }
          public void run(){
               update(c)
          }
          public static void main(String args[]){

               A t1 = new A();
               A t2 = new A();

               t1.start();
               t2.start();

          }
   }
```

This way the actual concept of synchronization will be applied.

Comment: i dont see how this is any helping with anything.

Comment: Synchronization is not getting achieved in your code.

Comment: Why would you say that Roam's synchronized block does not work? It synchronizes on the same object, c, that is modified inside the block. That will absolutely prevent two threads from entering that same block for the _same Object_, c. Sure, two threads can enter the block for two different Objects, but that's OK because they're modifying two _different_ objects, and there's no race condition in that case.