# Synchronizing on a lock object vs on the object processed

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

In the code of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278938/multi-threading-a-faster-way/24279254?noredirect=1#comment37513329_24279254) Q,

if I synchronize the block on some lock object 
instead of the object `c` itself, the code is executing 
almost twice faster with, from what i see, accurate results. Everything else in the code is the same:

```
public void update(SomeClass c) {

Object lock = new Object();
    while (<condition-1>) // the conditions here and the calculation of 
                               // k below dont have anything to do 
                               // with the members of c
        if (<condition-2>) {
            // calculate k here 
            synchronized (lock) {                        
                    c.setInt(c.getInt()+k); 
                //    System.out.println("in "+this.toString());
            }
        }  
}
```

Why is that so?

TIA

//=============================

EDIT:

With this lock above, the threads are running one after the other-- one thread is running the whole sequence, then another taking over the and running until all seq.is done & so forth. that's how i'm getting the accurate result. why is this happening w/this lock?

Comment: you are not actually blocking as `lock` in just a local variable

Comment: yes - ur right. in the above code, the other thing is the threads are running one after the other. that's how come i get the accurate result. i'll add this to the Q

Comment: That's what makes concurrency bugs so hard to find and fix.  You code can produce the right result 99.99% of the time, or it can _always_ produce the right result on _your_ system.  Then you ship it to a customer and it goes off the deep end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the update method from multiple threads (with the same SomeClass reference) and lock on c, then all of the threads will stand in line waiting for the lock to the c object.

If you instead lock on the lock object, a new one will get created on each method call , and each thread will synchronize on it's own lock (probably not what you intend), thus speeding the execution