# Obtaining the lock ofan object by running its synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

Running a synchronized method gives the lock of its object to the one invoking that method.

In the code of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278938/multi-threading-a-faster-way/24279254?noredirect=1#comment37513329_24279254) Q, 
do i need to synchronize the block at all-- on object `c` itself or on anything else?

`setInt()` is a synchronized method.

In the line

```
c.setInt(c.getInt()+k);
```

when `setInt()` is invoked, the lock of `c` is obtained since  `setInt()` is synch'd and 
the lock isn't released before `setInt()` returns. That's the entire block and no need t synch it(?)

So,

```
 c.setInt(c.getInt()+k);
```

would still be synchronized if i comment out "Line-A" & "Line-B" in the following code. setInt() is synchronized here, getInt() isn't:

```
public void update(SomeClass c) {

    while (<condition-1>) // the conditions here and the calculation of 
                               // k below dont have anything to do 
                               // with the members of c
        if (<condition-2>) {
            // calculate k here 
            synchronized (c) {      // Line-A                  
                    c.setInt(c.getInt()+k); 
                //    System.out.println("in "+this.toString());
            }                      // Line-B
        }  
}
```

This got me curious all along.

TIA

Comment: Don’t flood SO with tons of questions about the same issue. By the way, I gave you an [answer to your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24281311/2711488) which makes all other kludges unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to understand but I think you are asking if you are locked for the full call sequence there, the answer is that you are not. Effectively what you have put is the same as:

```
 int tmp = c.getInt(); // will lock and then unlock c
 tmp += k;
 c.setInt(tmp); // will lock and then unlock c.
```

This is why for proper thread safety you need an increment method which does both the get and set within one synchronized block.

i.e.

```
 c.increment(k);
```

Comment: Or just use an AtomicInteger :P

Comment: @omu_negru Yes, that would be better for this specific case. In the general case you need to understand this behaviour to do threading properly though.

Comment: i'm calling getInt() from within setInt(). getInt is not sync'd, getInt() is

Comment: @roam You are not calling getInt from within setInt. You are passing the results of a call to getInt as a parameter to setInt. The line you have in your code is identical in function to the one I posted using tmp and should show clearly why you do need the synchronized block.